# Render differences between iPad simulator and device?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I have an app which was originally designed a few years ago, just for the original iPhone. I've taken it on and we're looking to update it so that it works on iPhone 4 and iPads. There's quite a lot of code in it, so posting samples is difficult because they may not be from the right place (also it uses irrlicht, the majority of the code is c++ with a few obj-c classes - appDelegate etc).

The iPhone versions work fine, and in the xcode simulator the iPad version works fine. However on the device itself the iPad version does not render correctly.

The app is landscape in all versions, but on the iPad although it orientates everything the right way round, the draw area seems to be still be using the portrait orientation.
Here's a screenshot (ignore the green square, I've just hidden some info that was there): https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJWkq.png

As you can see the right hand side is blank, it seems to be limiting the width to 768, the image goes over the top of the screen (I would imagine it cuts off at 1024). Given that the iPhone version works fine, is there a setting in IB that may need changing that I could've overlooked?

Edit1:

```
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
        contentView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
        self.view = contentView;
        self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

Comment: As long as the main view is a controller, then you can set an autoResizigMask on the thing.

Comment: I haven't actually used autoresizingmask before, I've edited the question with the code I've added - does it look like a correct implementation?

Comment: yes autoresizingMask are used properly, whether this fixed your issue?

Comment: No. For some reason it has rotated the image itself now - and moved it over to the right hand side of the screen. If it was this autoresizingmask that was the issue - would that not be the case on iPhone devices as well? As I say it works fine on those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself - unfortunately when I was originally 'testing' it, I didn't have an ipad to hand so someone was testing each build which was very slow. Got hold of one and found the answer pretty quickly:

```
UIScreen* mainscr = [UIScreen mainScreen];

//original width and height
w = mainscr.currentMode.size.width;
h = mainscr.currentMode.size.height;


//fixed method
if((int)mainscr.currentMode.size.width % 1024 == 0)
    {
        w = mainscr.currentMode.size.width;
        h = mainscr.currentMode.size.height;
        //correct for ipad
    }
    else 
    {
        h = mainscr.currentMode.size.width;
        w = mainscr.currentMode.size.height;
        //correct for iphone
    }
```

For some reason I have to tell it to flip the orientation for ipads? Not sure why, but it works now, thanks for the help to all those who commented.